# one counter for multiple theorems?

Tags: sectioning, theorems, counters

I searched the internet for a while now but didn't quite get what i wanted.
I want number different theorems with the same counter, which depends on chapter and section. eg Lemma 1.1.1 Example 1.1.2 Proof 1.1.3...
I tried to define a counter like this but i get an error which says missing \begin{document} for the setcounter command but when i put it inside the document it doesn't work neither.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newcounter{cnt}[section]
\newcounter{thmcount}    
\setcounter{thmcount}{\thechapter.\thesection.\thecnt}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[thmcount]
\newtheorem{eg}{Example}[thmcount]
\newtheorem{pro}{Proof}[thmcount]

\begin{document}

\chapter{abc}
\section{xyz}

\begin{lem}
asdf
\end{lem}

\begin{eg}
fdsa
\end{eg}

\begin{pro}
sdaf
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]` and then for the others `\newtheorem{theo}[lem]{Theorem}` so they follow the counter `lem`.

Comment: For proofs, you can use `\begin{proof}\end{proof}` from `amsmath` package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to define a new counter:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{eg}[lem]{Example}
\newtheorem{pro}[lem]{Proof}

\begin{document}

\chapter{abc}
\section{xyz}

\begin{lem}
asdf
\end{lem}

\begin{eg}
fdsa
\end{eg}

\begin{pro}
sdaf
\end{pro}

\end{document}
```

The first `\newtheorem` sets up a new counter called `lem` (tied to `section`) that then is shared by all subsequent environments created with `lem` as optional argument just after the environment's name.